# InvalidOperationException: Can't set attributes via reference

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a Controller-class which is supposed to control the appearance of an object on the MainForm.
Whenever I try to alter a property of the UserControl (like Opacity here) within my Controller-class it fails with an `InvalidOperationException`

**EDIT:** This is the whole error-message:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll but was not handled in user code
>   The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private CubeControl _cube; //derived from System.Windows.Control.UserControl

    private CubeController _cubeController;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _cubeController = new CubeController(_cube);
    }
}
```

this is the Controller-class

```
public class CubeController
{

    /// <summary>A reference to the main cube control</summary>
    private CubeControl _cubeControl;

    public CubeController(CubeControl cubeControl)
    {
        _cubeControl = cubeControl;

        // this fails with an InvalidOperationException
        _cubeControl.Opacity = 0.3;     
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most probably you're not calling your property setter from the UI thread. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491889/wpf-system-invalidoperationexception-the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-obje

Comment: What is the message that comes with the `InvalidOperationException`?

Comment: _cube is null, isn't it? And are there any inner exceptions?

Comment: It works via `                    _cubeControl.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                            DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    new Action(() => _cubeControl.Opacity = `0.3));

Comment: Added the whole error-message